# Cassandra ReadTimeoutException while getting all records in a table even after overriding the timeout

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

So, I'm trying to get all records in a cassandra table (~10K records) using Java datastax 3.1 driver with the following query-level settings:

```
// |query| reads all records in a table (select * from table)
// Setting read timeout as 10 minutes
query.setReadTimeoutMillis(600000);
// Set page size as 1000
query.setFetchSize(1000);
```

Cassandra server settings are default (all default timeouts). It is a 3-node cluster.

Driver was able to read the first 1000 records successfully, but I started getting the following error every time driver was trying to fetch the next 1000 records.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:88)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:25)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.prepareNextRow(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:312)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.isExhausted(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:269)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$1.hasNext(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:143)
    ... <some more stacktrace of custom codebase trying to read all rows in a table>
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:115)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:124)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:500)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1012)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1280)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:890)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:564)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:505)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:419)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:391)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:62)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:277)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:257)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

So, the service which was reading all the records in the table went in a crash loop, with the same exception every time.

To my surprise, this exception was consistently occurring exactly 10sec after the 1000th record was read. It seems that 10sec is the cassandra server side timeout by default, which should have been overridden for my query to 600sec (clearly that didn't happen). Can anyone explain to me why this could have happened?

P.S. - After struggling for a long time to find the root cause, I restarted cassandra. And voila!, everything went smoothly after that, all the records were read in pages and processed without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The `select * from table` is the bad pattern - Cassandra isn't optimized for it, so it needs to fetch data from all the nodes, and stream through coordinator node.  The most effective way is to access data in Cassandra is by specifying partition key (maybe with additional conditions on clustering columns).

If you really need to scan all data in the cluster, you need to implement is as a set of token range queries going through all ranges in the cluster (you can obtain token ranges via `Metadata` class of Java or Python drivers).

Comment: You didn't answer the OP question but you answered my question